# Deploy Code on Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, deployment, bitbucket

When i try to run

```
git push heroku master
```

it gives error saying

```
fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

just before running this command I had pushed my code to bitbucket because of which

```
git remote -v
```

is showing

```
origin  https://prashant@bitbucket.org/prashant/code.git (fetch)
origin  https://prashant@bitbucket.org/prashant/code.git (push)
```

How can i deploy my code to heroku while continue my source code versioning on Bitbucket?

Is it necessary to change the remote origin everytime when

- I deploy my code on Heroku
- I push my code to Bitbucket

I know this sounds non sense, but as a beginner this is the only thing coming to my mind

**EDIT**
sequence of steps:

```
heroku login 

Git init

heroku create

git add . 

git commit -am "give some comment"

git remote add origin https://prashant@bitbucket.org/prashant/code.git

git push heroku master

fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to push a branch to Heroku, hence deploy the code, Heroku repository must be configured as a remote repository for your git project.

Which means, when you run `git remote` you should see the Heroku repo there.

To add link a repo to an existing Heroku app, simply use

```
$ git remote add heroku "PATH_TO_THE_HEROKU_APP"
```

See also https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#creating-a-heroku-remote

After that, you'll be able to deploy by running

```
$ git push heroku master
```

Comment: but then for my code changes will "git push origin master" will work (push my changes to bit bucket)?

Comment: Ah..my bad. now got it
So i have to add two remotes one for heroku and another for bitbucket

Comment: I was actually confused whther to add two remotes source will work or not.
BTW i know how to work with remote branch. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Heroku and Bitbucket is two different thing though some command are similar. Try this to deploy your app to heroku.

I assume you already have created account on heroku. If not [click here](https://signup.heroku.com/?c=70130000001xDpdAAE&gclid=Cj0KEQjwhtO7BRCtwuO9gfTH-fQBEiQAdJ8FY8vA9coCyx_300WRcmfvJyWboF0fnB2iRCiPtdQz9lYaAmYL8P8HAQ) and make one.

Go to your terminal, change the directory to where your app is and run below commands

```
heroku login 

Git init

heroku create

git add . 

git commit -am "give some comment"

git push heroku master
```

This will work, read this for more information on what is git , heroku , and GitHub (GitHub is similar to Bitbucket)

Comment: I know the differences, and i did the similar steps you have mentioned, the only difference being that after "git commit" and before "push" I had set remote origin to point to bitbucket and after that "git push heroku master " is giving the error i mentioned in my question

Comment: I had added the exact sequence of steps I did and landed into problem